# How to use django formsets to do a questionnaire

Tags: python, django, django-forms, formsets

I'm doing an application and now I need to make an evaluation that users can take, my problem is that I want to use a formset to list the questions with respective choices, I know this can be done with using formsets but not the way to get it done. Following is my code:

```
# models.py

class Evaluation(models.Model):
    """
    An evaluation is for a session.
    Each session should have an evaluation
    """
    session = models.OneToOneField(
        Session,
        related_name='evaluation',
        verbose_name=u'Sesión'
    )

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = u'Evaluación'
        verbose_name_plural = u'Evaluaciones'

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'Evaluación de la sesion {0}'.format(
            self.session.name
        )


class Question(models.Model):
    """
    A question inside of an evaluation
    """
    evaluation = models.ForeignKey(
        Evaluation,
        verbose_name=u'Evaluación',
        related_name='questions'
    )
    question_type = models.CharField(
        max_length=20,
        verbose_name=u'Tipo de respuesta',
        choices=QUESTION_TYPES
    )
    sentence = models.CharField(
        max_length=255,
        verbose_name=u'Pregunta'
    )
    position = models.IntegerField(
        default=0,
        verbose_name=u'Posición'
    )

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = u'Pregunta'
        verbose_name_plural = u'Preguntas'
        ordering = ['position', 'sentence']

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.sentence


class Choice(models.Model):
    question = models.ForeignKey(
        Question,
        related_name='choices',
        verbose_name=u'Pregunta'
    )
    sentence = models.CharField(
        max_length=255,
        verbose_name=u'Posible respuesta'
    )
    position = models.IntegerField(
        default=0,
        verbose_name=u'Posición'
    )

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = u'Posible respuesta'
        verbose_name_plural = u'Posibles respuestas'
        ordering = ['position', 'sentence']

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.sentence

----

# forms.py

from django.forms.models import inlineformset_factory
from models import Evaluation, Question


AnswerFormSet = inlineformset_factory(
    Evaluation, Question, exclude=('question',),
    extra=0, can_delete=False
)

----

# views.py

@login_required()
def session_evaluation(request, course_slug, session_position):
    data = {}
    course = get_object_or_404(Course, slug=course_slug)
    session = Session.objects.filter(course=course).get(position=session_position)
    evaluation = get_object_or_404(Evaluation, session=session)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        formset = AnswerFormSet(request.POST, instance=evaluation)
        if formset.is_valid():
            formset.save()
            print 'formset valid...'
    else:
        formset = AnswerFormSet(instance=evaluation)
    data['course'] = course
    data['session'] = session
    data['formset'] = formset
    return render(request, 'courses/session_evaluation.html', data)

----

# template.html
<form id="evaluation" method="post" role="form">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ formset.management_form }}
    <ul class="evaluation">
        {% for form in formset.forms %}
            <li>
                {{ form.instance }}
                {{ form.instance.choices.all }}
            </li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
    <div class="form-group clearfix nmb">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary pull-right">Enviar respuestas</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

As you can see I have the models well written but from the forms all the code is only an experiment and I really don't know the way to do it.

What I'm getting in the template with this code is the question sentence and the list of choices, something like:

```
[question sentence here]? [<Choice: [choice #1 here]>, <Choice: [choice #2 here]>]
```

What is the clean and easy way to do it with formsets?

What I want to get is a list of questions with the respective list of choices with radio buttons because this is an evaluation.

Answer (score 0):

Should not it be `{{ form.as_p }}` or `{{ form.as_table }}`? The instance is already created in the view, so need not be used in the template.